# OpenTSDB curl post issue

Tags: curl, opentsdb

I am using the following `curl` command to push metrics to `opentsdb`

```
curl -X POST --data-binary gzip.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Content-Encoding: gzip" http://mycloud:xxxx/api/put?details
```

and getting

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

However `opentsdb` is up and running and I can query using `/api/query/` too. Can you identify which part I'm wrong at?

Comment: The curl call seems ok, only one thing - use @ with the data i.e. @gzip.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl call seems ok, only one thing - use `@` with the data i.e. `@gzip.json`

Your call will be:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "@gzip.json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Content-Encoding: gzip" http://mycloud:xxxx/api/put?details
```

---

Source: [Compressed Request section](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/index.html)